# Cannot reach the password of the user after assigning it - RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write system tests. I want to run a classic login page test.
I have a field for email, password, and submit button.

It is working in production env and alive without any problem.

my test file is like this:

```
it "can login" do
      user = User.create(email: 'mail@mail.com', password: 'password', role:1, name: 'test user')
      user.save!

      visit '/'
      fill_in(:user_email, with: user.email)
      fill_in(:user_password, with: 'password')

      find(:button, 'Sign in').click
      expect(page).to have_content('Signed in.')
    end
```

Whenever I tried to create a user and try to use it in the system testing, it is not working. It is visiting the page, filling the places and clicking the button as it should but it cannot log in, giving error that email or password is not correct.

I believe there is a problem with password encryption or somehow I cannot match the passwords properly.
I have printed out the user after creation in the test case, I have a valid user but somehow I cannot reach its password. I checked the model, there is not a 'password' field. ( I am working on a company project, that is why I am having difficulty to find the problem )
I can assign a password with using `user.password = ...` but I cannot call it back it seems. (I tried this in rails console, assigning worked, calling back did not and I could use the user and the password for logging in manually)

EDIT:
I found out that the problem is database matching. I could create the user but the test is not using that user...

Comment: What is the app using to manage your authentication?  Devise, authlogic, has_secure_password etc.

Comment: I believe it is device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because of data transaction. I changed it truncation for system testing and it worked! It was basically flushing all the data before using it. That was why I was getting error.